# question related to reverse function and kwargs

Tags: python, django

To reverse lookup an url by means of name or View_name we will use reverse function in the views like below

```
reverse("calendarviewurl2", kwargs={"year":theyear,"month":themonth})
```

and reverse function signature is as follows

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py

```
def reverse(self, lookup_view, *args, **kwargs)
```

My question is related to kwargs

when we want to send a dictionary as keyword arguments we should use the below syntax
 ***snippet 1***

```
 kwargs={"year":2009,"month":9}
   reverse("name",**kwargs)
```

as opposed to below code
***snippet 2***

```
  reverse("name",kwargs={"year":2009,"month":9})
```

So my question  is

1. Do the snippet1 and snippet2 are
   same? ( i feel they are not same)
2. In case of reverse function only
   snippet 2 is working where as
   snippet 1 is not properly working.Why is it so? (Even though the proper way to send a dictionary is by using syntax mentioned in snippet1.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Didn't you look at the [signature](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py#L305),

```
def reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, 
                      prefix=None, current_app=None):
```

takes no `**kwargs` at all.

```
kwargs={"year":2009,"month":9}
reverse("name",**kwargs)
```

means

```
reverse("name", year=2009, month=9)
```

which is completely different from

```
reverse("name",kwargs={"year":2009,"month":9})
```

When a function actually does take `**kwargs`, both ways to call it are the same. But that's not the case here. Reverse would have look like this to take `**kwargs`:

```
def reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, prefix=None, 
                      current_app=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
I missed the second reverse definition in the file 
http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py
I have just seen the first reverse  definaion trying hard to know the reason.